# ¿cómo haría una aplicación consola para que tenga siguiente funciones?

Tags: java

Insertar Datos Alumno:

1-Se selecciona la fila donde desea insertar (o asignar) los datos

2-Se le solicitan los datos anteriores al usuario y se colocan en las columnas respectivas

3-Se debe verificar si la fila ya posee datos

4-Se debe verificar si todas las columnas de la fila poseen un valor de 0 (String)

MatrixAlumnos[fila][columna] == “0“
Si, todas las columnas poseen “0”, se puede asignar los datos.
Si no, se muestra los datos actuales de la fila, además un mensaje de error “El usuario ya posee datos”.

Nombre
Luis
david
juan
carlos
maria
Primer apellido
d
d
d
d
d
Segundo apellido
c
c
c
c
c
Cedula

Nota1
65
75
85
55
45
Nota2
55
85
66
44
45
Nota3
44
455
55
55
55

```
package javaapplication38;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaApplication38 {

    private final int largoArreglo = 5;
    private final int matrizFila = 5;
    private final int matrizColumna = 7;

    int arreglo[] = new int[largoArreglo];
    int arreglo1[] = new int[largoArreglo];
    int arreglo12[] = new int[largoArreglo];

    
    int matriz[][] = new int[matrizFila][matrizColumna];
    //[5][5] = 25 espacios/variables/casillas

    ArrayList<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<String>();

    public JavaApplication38() {
        for (int i = 0; i < largoArreglo; i++) {
            arreglo[i] = 0;
        }

    }

    public void InsertarDatos1( int dato,int indiceF, int indiceC ) {

        if ((indiceF >= 0 && indiceF < matrizFila) && (indiceC >= 0 && indiceC < matrizColumna)) {
            matriz[indiceF][indiceC] =dato;
            

            System.out.println("ya posee datos");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El usuario ya posee datos");

        }
    }

    public void MostarDatosDeLaMatriz() {
        for (int x = 0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("columna %d y fila %d de la matrix", x, y));
                System.out.println(String.format("Tiene un valor de %d", matriz[x][y]));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estaría bueno que pongas una parte de tu código y donde necesitas ayuda.

Comment: No sé cómo insertar los datos de nombre y apellido

Comment: El enunciado dice en una parte: Se debe verificar si todas las columnas de la fila poseen un valor de 0 (String).
Te aconsejo un replanteamiento del problema y en vez de manejar datos del tipo int, manejar datos del tipo String.
Al momento de insertar los datos (en vez de pasarle datos del tipo int, pasarles datos del tipo String),los numeros se los pasas como "2" (porque es tipo String) y los nombre como "Juan" también te los tomará como tipo string.